# Redeliver existing form submission to new webhook

Tags: rest, salesforce, typeform

I have set up a webhook between salesforce and Typeform and it's working fine. But Typeform has already filled form submissions. Now I want to deliver these responses to a new webhook is there a way to resync existing form submissions?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think this is possible out of the box. You will need to fetch your responses via [Typeform Responses API](https://developer.typeform.com/responses/) and feed them to your script or webhook.

It looks like the [webhook payload](https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/example-payload/) is quite similar to the [response returned by the API](https://developer.typeform.com/responses/reference/retrieve-responses/). You can write a script like this to feed all your existing responses from your typeform to a new webhook:

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import crypto from 'crypto'
import { createClient } from '@typeform/api-client'

const token = process.env.TF_TOKEN // https://developer.typeform.com/get-started/personal-access-token/
const webhookSecret = process.env.SECRET
const uid = process.env.FORM_ID

const typeformAPI = createClient({ token })

const sleep = async (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

// based on https://glitch.com/edit/#!/tf-webhook-receiver
const calculateSignature = (payload) => {
  const hash = crypto
    .createHmac('sha256', webhookSecret)
    .update(payload)
    .digest('base64')
  return `sha256=${hash}`
}

const feedResponses = (before) => {
  typeformAPI.responses.list({ uid, before }).then(async ({ items }) => {
    if (items.length > 0) {
      // process each response
      for (let i=0; i<items.length; i+=1) {
        const item = items[i]
        const body = JSON.stringify({
          "event_id": Date.now(),
          "event_type": "form_response",
          "form_response": item
        })
        const response = await fetch('/your-endpoint', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Typeform-Signature': calculateSignature(body)
          },
          body,
        })
        const webhookResponse = await response.text()
        console.log(webhookResponse)
        await sleep(250) // rate-limit the requests
      }

      // continue with next page of responses
      const { token } = items.at(-1)
      feedResponses(token)
    }
  })
}

feedResponses()
```